Probabilty of a Plinko game to end.
I was pondering a game (similar to plinko) where a ball is dropped, and each level it either moves 1 unit to the right or the left. However, instead of ending when the ball reaches the bottom, we have the game go an infinite length in the down direction and the game will end when the ball reaches the side.
To start out, we keep the sides horizontal with a distance $2n$ between them. If we then drop the ball in the center of the two sides, the probability the game will end is 1. This is because we need at most $2n$ moves to the right in a row; given we have an infinite length for this to happen it must happen at some point.
However, I am stuck on what happens if we have the sides expanding as you go down the plinko board. In the limiting case where the board is expanding by more than 2 units (1 in each direction) for every level, we have that the probability for the game to end is 0. But what happens when the board expands say one unit on each side for every $k$ levels down?
I can see that this is equivalent to having a 1-dimensional random walk starting at the origin and finding the probability that the walk intersects some bound $|x| = n + \frac{1}{k}t$. In addition to just finding the probability that the game ends, can we find the expected value for the game to end at?

Random walks like this generally diverge as the square root of the length of the walk, so I imagine if the width at depth $n$ broadens at least at that pace, there will be some non-zero probability that the ball never reaches the sides. A closed form for any arbitrary boundary seems hard, though.
